# Rewriting Subdomains in IIS

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, subdomain

I'm having some trouble rewriting some things in IIS

Here is what I'm trying to achieve.

We have a bunch of clients that all need a subdomain.  For example

http://clientA.mysite.com needs to be rewritten to http://mysite.com/clientArea/?clientID=1234

Then all content needs to be rewrriten to http://mysite.com/clientArea/XXX

so for example if someone requests http://clientA.mysite.com/example.css , that should be rewritten to http://mysite.com/clientArea/example.css

I cannot for the life of me get this working right.

I think I have to to do this in 2 rules.  I think I have the first rule working kindof (page looks whack because it can't get the JS files or CSS files to make it look right)

Here is my first rule to rewrite http://clientA.mysite.com to http://mysite.com/clientArea/?clientID=1234

```
<rule name="Rewrite Subdomain" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="()" />
     <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)clientA\.mysite\.com$" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="clientArea/?clientID=1234" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
 </rule>
```

My second rule, however, I cannot get to work, so any help with this would be great

```
<rule name="Rewrite Everything Else after subdomain">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)clientA\.mysite\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
 </rule>
```

Requesting things like http://clientA.mysite.com/example.js returns a 404 error.

Thanks for the time,
Kyle

Answer (score 0):

If you have dedicated IP number for your site, you can add empty http binding to your site in IIS (right click on your site in IIS > Edit bindings > Add). Then add DNS 'A' record with value: * in your DNS configuration. As a result, every call to your IP will be maintained by your site.

Answer (score -1):

You use a combination in inbound and outbound rewritting rules along with the Application Request Routing Module.

Inbound rule proxies the subfolder to the subdomain content.  Outbound rule examines the response and replaces all instances of the subdomain in the response with your subfolder path.